# 'Migrate Routes' fail when upgrading from Orchard 1.3.9 to Orchard 1.7

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I'm in the process of upgrading an Orchard site from 1.3.9 to 1.7.

I'm using the *Upgrade* module, and when attempting to upgrade Routes (last tab) the code fails, at the point where it attempts to access a newly created AutoroutePart.

Specifically, inside `RouteController.IndexPOST()` :

```
// migrating parts
_contentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition(contentType,
    builder => builder
        .WithPart("AutoroutePart")
        .WithPart("TitlePart"));

// force the first object to be reloaded in order to get a valid AutoroutePart
_orchardServices.ContentManager.Clear();
```

This code snippet is supposed to assign an *AutoroutePart* and a *TitlePart* to the type at hand (let's say it's a *Page* but obviously any other type in the checkbox list of the Routes tab). But it fails to do so. Because later on the assignment

```
var autoroutePart = ((ContentItem)content).As<AutoroutePart>();
```

fails and `autoroutePart` is null, and then further down the code fails with an `Object reference not set...` error when it attempts to access `autoroutePart.ContentItem.Id`.

Eventually I was able to bypass it by manually entering a record in table `Settings_ContentTypePartDefinitionRecord` that maps a Page (ContentType ID 2) to Autoroute and Title part IDs but that seems awkward and error-prone, and I must have missed something (not to mention having to apply this hack to the rest of the content types).

What can cause `AlterTypeDefinition` to not apply these records in the database?

Comment: Painful as it is, you might want to try to migrate to 1.4 first.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy if so, someone probably needs to update the instructions at http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-1-7-Release-Notes .... BTW thanks for a great product!

Comment: It works for most people. I'm sorry it doesn't for you.

Comment: Regardless of the upgrade process, it seems like a clear bug in the code snippet I presented. A very specific thing should have happened and from some reason didn't (many-to-many records being created in table Settings_ContentTypePartDefinitionRecord)

Comment: It's not clear to me, but if you want to file a bug with precise repro steps, please do.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? Btw, where did you find the Upgrade module?? I'm on 1.3.10 and in my Modules section there's no trace of an Upgrade module, and I can not find it in the gallery... quite painful...

Comment: @Wasp eventually yes, with lots of direct DB hacking... no magic spell I'm afraid. It was really hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using the new transaction system.

The idea is that `ITransactionManager.RequireNew()` is called before and after each piece of code that needs to be committed to the database.  A few of the calls in my code example are redundant but I figure this code is only going to be used once so rather than try to optimize unneeded calls away, I would leave them in to indicate where transactions start and end.

Providing a diff as a gist.

https://gist.github.com/harmony7/10621982